# Showing the equivalence of two solutions to a second order, linear differential equation with complex roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+x=0$, there are (at least) two general solutions one can immediately write down, namely:

Solution 1: $x(t)=  c_1sin(t) + c_2cos(t)$

Solution 2: $x(t)=  Acos(t-t_0)$

It is trivial to show that each solution satisfies the differential equation. What is less obvious to me, is to show that those two solutions, independent of the fact that they are solutions to the differential equations, are in fact equivalent? In other words, can we prove that Solution 1 is equivalent to Solution 2, without even referencing the differential equation?

Comment: Thank you--that trig expansion makes sense, but wouldn't we need to impose some sort of initial conditions in order to make the claim that $c_1$ = $c_2$ = $A$, in which case the solution wouldn't be general, right?

Comment: Also, if we are setting $t_0 =0$, how could we arrive at the final step of your proposed equations?